# Ruby/Rails: parse a file and create active record associations from parsed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, parsing

I have a boatload of text files (see below) that I need to parse. They contain chapter information that I'd like to capture and use to create associated records. `Report has_many :chapters`

Basically I need to read each line and for each `BookmarkTitle` capture the chapter name (ignoring the CR `&#13;`) and then capture the `BookmarkPageNumber`. Then bundle the pairing up and create a new record with it: `report.page.create(title: bookmark_title, page_number: bookmark_page_number)`

I've played a bit with [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines)'s readline but not sure how to capture the contents... a RegEx perhaps? or a more Rails-y way?

sample txt file:

```
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: Adobe Acrobat 9.3.4
InfoKey: Producer
InfoValue: Adobe Acrobat 9.34 Paper Capture Plug-in
InfoKey: ModDate
InfoValue: D:20110315193536-04'00'
InfoKey: CreationDate
InfoValue: D:20110208171413-05'00'
PdfID0: 2dab1ce43882a53cbc24dbb839f921f8
PdfID1: 43b19192e920f38f65de0bf0a2be
NumberOfPages: 258
BookmarkTitle: 1980 Field Service Annual Report&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 3
BookmarkTitle: TABLE OF CONTENTS&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 4
BookmarkTitle: LIST OF EXHIBITS&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 7
BookmarkTitle: I - INTRODUCTION&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 11
BookmarkTitle: II - EXECUTIVE SUMMARY&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 16
BookmarkTitle: III - RESULTS AND ANALYSIS OF THE MAINTENANCE USER SURVEY&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 45
BookmarkTitle: IV - COMPARATIVE ANALYSIS OF BIGCO AND OTHER MAINTENANCE VENDORS&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 102
BookmarkTitle: V - RESULTS OF VENDOR SURVEY&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 127
BookmarkTitle: VI - SIGNIFICANT VENDOR ACTIVITIES, 1979-1980&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 190
BookmarkTitle: APPENDIX A:  DEFINITIONS&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 199
BookmarkTitle: APPENDIX B:  RESEARCH METHODOLOGY&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 204
BookmarkTitle: APPENDIX C:  SUPPORTING CHARTS&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 211
BookmarkTitle: APPENDIX D:  USER QUESTIONNAIRE&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 222
BookmarkTitle: APPENDIX E:  VENDOR QUESTIONNAIRE&#13;
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 237
```

Comment: regex would be fine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^BookmarkTitle:\s*(.+?)&#13;\s*BookmarkLevel:\s*(\d+)\s*BookmarkPageNumber:\s*(\d+)\s*$/m
```

I'm sorry, I'm not a Ruby-On-Rails Developer, but that regular expression will match each bookmark, and return:

- The entire record
- The Title (as a sub-match)
- The Level (as a sub-match)
- The Page number (as a sub-match)

It does assume that level and page number are numeric without spaces, comma or decimals.  But that could easily by changed.

Comment: great! very helpful. so...now how to I get ahold of those values from within my Rails app?!? Sorry, I haven't worked much with RegEx and when I do I seem to forget rather quickly how/what I did before...

Comment: Seems like I would want to read each line and see if that RegEx hits. once I populate the `Title` and `PageNumber` then I can create a record and move on. I don't care (nor even know) about the BookmarkLevel.

Comment: Not knowing much about Ruby, here's a tutorial that seems useful:  http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_regular_expressions.html

Also, no.  Don't read each line separately.  This regex is counting on matching across lines.  You would need a completely different set of regexes to do it line by line.

Comment: FWIW: In Rails you can scan a string like so: `matchArray = stringWithContentToBeMatched.scan(myRegex)` where `myRegex` is your match string.